# why did my vba coding output be like this?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my coding, I want to build an update drop down list from the database that I create from another sheet in Excel, but the error keep distract my coding, how I want to solve it?

> [image: Microsoft ODBC Excel Driver; Too few parameters. Expected 1.]
>
> <sub>Microsoft ODBC Excel Driver; Too few parameters. Expected 1.</sub>

The error occurs on this instruction:

```
rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Here's the surrounding code:

```
Option Explicit 
Public Cnn As New ADODB.Connection 
Public Rs As New ADODB.Recordset 
Public StrSQL As String 

Public Sub OpenDB() 
    If Cnn.State = adStateOpen Then Cnn.Close 
    Cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _ 
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name 
Cnn.Open 
End Sub 

Public Sub CloseRS() 
    If Rs.State = adStateOpen Then Rs.Close 
    Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
strSQL = "Select Distinct [Equipment] From [mechanical$] Order by [Equipment]"
    CloseRS
    OpenDB
    ComboBox1.Clear

    rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic '<<< ERROR HERE
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            ComboBox1.AddItem rs.Fields(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Products.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Function
    End If

    '----------------------------
    strSQL = "Select Distinct [SWEC] From [mechanical$] Order by [SWEC]"
    CloseRS
    OpenDB
    ComboBox2.Clear

    rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            ComboBox2.AddItem rs.Fields(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Region(s).", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Function
    End If
    '----------------------
    strSQL = "Select Distinct [Principal Name] From [mechanical$] Order by [Principal Name]"
    CloseRS
    OpenDB
    ComboBox3.Clear

    rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            ComboBox3.AddItem rs.Fields(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Customer Type(s).", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

> here my output page [search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE8Qc.png)
>   my database [databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3MHx.png)

Comment: You said you get an error, but you haven't told us what the error is.

Comment: rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic - this the line that error - it pop up a message that write " run time error '424' object required

Comment: another error on the same line is run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)': [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Comment: That information needs to be in your post, you can [edit] it any time.

Comment: i already added the info, the image is in the word that in blue

Comment: Not everyone can see the pictures.

Comment: In MS Access, that error means that you have mispelled the name of a column or object and it incorrectly thinks it's a parameter. So triple check your column names. Try some variations on the SQL statement to try and isolate it. It's great that you have some working SQL in the section before that based on `[Equipment]`. You can use that as a base for troubleshooting

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the information was originally in a screenshot, revisions [4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44688703/4), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44688703/6) and [7](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44688703/7) were pointing the wrong instruction... there's no working SQL Truth is, we need to know what `CloseRS` and `OpenDB` do, and where & how `rs` is obtained.

Comment: i already check the column, and i not misspelled it .. another way that i can solve it , i just want to link with the column on the database so that my update drop down button will be function \

Comment: about your  cnn variable , it caused error.  describe the cnn's  string.

Comment: The error looks more like a SQL error than a connection error

Comment: You're correct - there's a lot of missing code. I made some assumptions but that's a very bad idea when troubelshoting. @NissaAnnissa, does the prior line work - the one the refers to `[Equipment]`?

Comment: is there other way that i can create update drop down button using vba coding

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiZhH.png

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid [Equipment] did not work bcoz of the error by  
rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Comment: @NissaAnnissa to be fair, your code has that exact same instruction in 3 different places.

Comment: Well that makes a huge difference to your description of the error. Does any data stuff work? I am going to edit your original post and mark where the error occurs.Then we will be at a stage where we can actually do some analysis. You really should add all the code that populates `Cnn` and `rs` as well.

Comment: Oh... now I see it's in the question. Does any of your data code work?

Comment: only for this coding not work, other coding work @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: @Mat'sMug yes, i use it for three column to update the drop down list

Comment: Do you have any other code that runs `Select Distinct [Equipment] From [mechanical$] Order by [Equipment]` successfully? I suggest you find out what columns Excel ODBC thinks you have. Change the statement to `Select * From [mechanical$]` then put a breakpoint on your `rs.Open` line and inspect `rs.Fields`. I can explain further if you wish but only if you are interested in uncovering the real issue

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE8Qc.png this is my output page, to be cleared and u can see it that i want to update the comboBox from the database https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3MHx.png

Comment: how i want to find out what excel ODBC think that i have ? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: You think you have a sheet called `mechanical` and a column called `Equipment`, but the error you get _appears_ to indicate that this is not the case. You need to find out what columns your VBA code thinks you have. So you need to select all columns using `Select Distinct [Equipment] From [mechanical$]` in your code, then you need to debug your code and see what is returned in `rs.Fields[0]`, `rs.Fields[1]`, `rs.Fields[2]` etc., to find out what the column names really are. Can you try that? You need to change your SQL and set a breakpoint on the `rs.Open` line

Comment: I guess you got your code from here: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database/ . At this stage I think that you probably have bigger problems. Perhaps you could screenshot your excel sheet, post the code for `CloseRS` and `OpenDB`

Comment: is the coding have problem @Nick.McDermaid i take the code from there, i cant screenshot the excel sheet bcoz of the data is PnC , i already screenshot the layout, or i need to update the module on the vba coding ?

Comment: We cannot suggest any magic code to fix this because the code you have should work (inefficiently). I believe the columns aren't what you think they are, and I have suggested ways in the comments for you to debug it.

Comment: Option Explicit
Public Cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Public Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public StrSQL As String

Public Sub OpenDB()
    If Cnn.State = adStateOpen Then Cnn.Close
    Cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Cnn.Open
End Sub

Public Sub CloseRS()
    If Rs.State = adStateOpen Then Rs.Close
    Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
End Sub

is this coding correct @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I'll add it to your question

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (except that it's inefficient and uses globals). Your code is trying to select from columns on your excel file that don't exist. Your Excel file is the problem. But you've checked your excel file and you say the columns exist. I explained a number of times how you could verify what columns exist. It's not a matter of correct code, it's a matter of knowing how to debug code. Read this, and try and work out what columns VBA thinks are in your excel file. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the code wold be like.

```
Option Explicit
Public Cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Public Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public StrSQL As String

Public Sub OpenDB()
    If Cnn.State = adStateOpen Then Cnn.Close
    Cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

Cnn.Open
End Sub

Public Sub CloseRS()
    If Rs.State = adStateOpen Then Rs.Close
    Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
End Sub
```

Comment: rs.RecordCount  is nothing!!

Comment: what do you meant by nothing ?

Comment: rs.RecordCount is not assisted.  I find your code have  something fale else. I modified your code .

Comment: Rs.Open strSQL, Cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
change Rs.Open strSQL, Cnn

Comment: the error message pop out " no value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: In my method adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic  is not allowed. so  delete them.     change   Rs.Open strSQL, Cnn

Comment: I modified my answer. The the other code of you is correct. ConnectionString hase been incorrected.

Comment: I confuse  rs.recordcount.   this is not assisted in CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") method, but in your method it is assisted.